# Which of these five statements about lvalues is true?

Tags: c, variable-assignment, operator-keyword, lvalue, rvalue

I'm doing the following puzzle. Mayby someone could check if I'm choosing the right answer.
Have a look.

Which one of the following is a true statement about an lvalue?

1 An lvalue is the result of an arithmetic operation involving quantities of type long int.

2 All lvalues can be used on the right side of an assignment statement.

3 An lvalue is, by definition, the value appearing on the rightmost side of an assignment
statement.

4 By definition, an lvalue is the storage space indirectly referenced by a pointer.

5 An lvalue is any quantity capable of appearing on the left side of a shift operator.

Ok, an lvalue is the  reference to an object in memory. Therefore, at first sight I thought of the 4th answer but now it seems not the right one, as lvalue is not the stoage itself (and answer 4 implies that). #
I'm thinking then that **answer 2 is correct** as lvalues can be used on left and right hand side of the assignment operator.
What do you think?

Comment: This looks an awful lot like homework...

Comment: The more straightforward problem with #4 is that you don't need to have any pointers involved at all for an expression to be an lvalue.

Comment: @TylerJandreau What's the problem with that? It's homework for sure, but OP has made the effort answering it, and apparently he answered it right, and he just asked for confirmation.

Comment: @H2CO3 There isn't a problem with it. It was merely an observation. And the OP said he was doing a "puzzle", which makes me thing he/she is trying to hide the actual intent of the question. I don't mind answering homework, just label it as such.

Comment: HI guys. I'll clarify. These puzzles (as they can be called;p) I am doing because often you need to do such test as part of the job interview. I am now in last year of my studies which don't hold programming in C. I feel I'm getting better and better in C, learning from books (for example, Kernighan&Ritchie) but sometimes it needs more than that... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm thinking then that answer 2 is correct as lvalues can be used on left and right hand side of the assignment operator

Yes, this one is true, for this exact reason.

The problem with the other statements:

> 1) An lvalue is the result of an arithmetic operation involving quantities of type long int.

No. Being `long int` or not does not have anything to do with lvalues. `(long int)42` is of type `long int`, yet it's not an lvalue.

> 3) An lvalue is, by definition, the value appearing on the rightmost side of an assignment statement.

No. I don't know if that has any special name, but that's not the definition of lvalue for sure.

> 4) By definition, an lvalue is the storage space indirectly referenced by a pointer.

No. You don't need any pointers for that. As in `int i = 1337;`, `i` is an lvalue. No pointers in the code whatsoever, though.

> 5) An lvalue is any quantity capable of appearing on the left side of a shift operator.

No. At first glance, lvalues have more to do with the ability to being modified in some way (assignment to a variable or to a member of an array), so this statement would be closer to true if instead of `shift operator` it read `assignment operator`. However, not all lvalues can be modified (for example a constant is an lvalue, yet it can't be modified after initializing it).

Comment: What you describe at the end is a modifiable lvalue. `const int i;`,  `i` cannot appear on the left side of the `=` operator but yet it is a lvalue. A lvalue is an object locator.

Comment: Re: 4, with `register int i;` `i` is an lvalue even though you can't even take its address (it doesn't have one). Re: 5, arrays can't appear on the LHS of `=` but they're also lvalues.

Comment: @ouah True, will fix that.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, right. That's an error. I'll delete the erroneous statement.